# Load asset file at Startup failed, file does not exists

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I need to load some asset data to my middleware, but it seems like it can't load the file.

Here's the folder structure:

[image]

As you can see, it's already set to "Copy if newer". And the file does get copied over to the bin folder:

[image]

Here's the code at ConfigureServices:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        var assetFile = Configuration["Assets/Files"];
        var testExist = File.Exists(assetFile);    // This will be false
        //services.AddAsset();
    }
```

Here's the appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Assets": {
    "Files": "Assets/something.zip"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

As of now, my only guess is there is file size limit? The .zip file is 165MB large. Just my wild guess, else I don't know why it couldn't find my file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the config setting ins't read properly, that's why it cannot locate the file.

Try replacing this line:

```
var assetFile = Configuration["Assets/Files"];
```

with this one:

```
var assetFile = Configuration["Assets:Files"];
```

Notice that I used **colons** to navigate in the appsettings.json keys, instead of a **forward slash**.